# Can't make bootstrap dialog modeless

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dialog, modeless

I'm trying to create a dialog using Bootstrap 3.2.0.  I have them working fine except for those that I want to be modeless.  I've set the `data-backdrop` attribute to false and I've tried some of the suggestions I've found online such as detaching the focus event:

```
$(document).off("focusin.bs.modal");
```

and/or removing the `modal-open` class from the `body` tag.

After doing these things you can still see the content in the window, but the user cannot interact with it at all in Chrome and Firefox, while they can to some extent in IE 10.

Is it possible to create a truly modeless dialog using Bootstrap?

Comment: Do you mean [like this example?](http://www.bootply.com/n8EQQaoIeK)

Comment: Yes, that example demonstrates the problem exactly.  In Chrome and Firefox, you can't click on the button again once the dialog is open.  But in IE 10 you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be accomplished. See [this functioning demo](http://www.bootply.com/PXw32SCBMe)

On the modal div add a class for modeless:

```
<div class="modal fade modeless" ...
```

Then add CSS for it:

```
.modeless{
    top:10%;
    left:50%;
    bottom:auto;
    right:auto;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
```

Note that the `margin-left` is what is centering it. The default size for the bs modal is 600px for screens over 768px wide. You will need to adjust it for whatever size modal you are using, and it would probably be a good idea to add some media queries to cover breakpoints if need be.

HTH -Ted

Comment: thank you very much.  This worked perfectly!  Appreciate the help.

Comment: It is not modeless. If you put an input near the launch button and try to focus it while popup is visible you won't be able to do it. It is beneath 50% background.

Comment: It doesn't works for content below the dialog and from right and bottom side of the dialog. And if the dialog is draggable, it can be dragged beneath top-left content